# When to use Visual Studio C# "Validated" / "Validating" Events

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio C#, when would you use the "Validated" or "Validating" events for a text box on a form instead of just coding a try-catch statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), by calling the Select or SelectNextControl methods, or by setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form, focus events occur in the following order:

- Enter
- GotFocus
- Leave
- Validating
- **Validated**
- LostFocus

When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus method, focus events occur in the following order:

- Enter
- GotFocus
- LostFocus
- Leave
- Validating
- **Validated**

If the CausesValidation property is set to false, the Validating and Validated events are suppressed.

I noted this for you as they are in a different order.. just for info...

Anyway... you would then use a try catch within the validating / validated event handler to ensure that no exceptions are thrown to the screen and set a message etc etc.

Hope this helps to clear things up?

Matthew